# Capture repeating groups using sed

Tags: sed

I'm looking to use sed to capture repeating groups in order to parse a log line

```
echo "14:14:52.449 [thread] INFO  LOGGER - SYMBOL: FIELD1[1.0] FIELD2[2] FIELD3[141452 (2016-11-24 14:14:52.000)] FIELD4[4]" | sed -E "s/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d )(.*?\-)( .*?\:)(.*)( FIELD3\[.*?\]).*/\\1\\3\\5/"
```

I'm looking to capture only the following fields

```
14:14:52.449 SYMBOL FIELD3[141452 (2016-11-24 14:14:52.000)]
```

However I get the entire line back. Any help is deeply appreciated

```
14:14:52.449 [thread] INFO  LOGGER - SYMBOL: FIELD1[1.0] FIELD2[2] FIELD3[141452 (2016-11-24 14:14:52.000)] FIELD4[4]
```

Comment: sed doesn't support non-greedy... `.*?` won't work.. `\d` isn't valid too.. need to use `[0-9]` you can use `perl` instead or find a way to avoid non-greedy regex...

Comment: expected output has `TIME` which doesn't appear in input... also, could you explain in words on what basis you want to extract fields?

Comment: `perl -pe 's/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d )(.*?\-)( .*?\:)(.*)( FIELD3\[.*?\]).*/$1$3$5/'` would be direct translation from your `sed` attempt to `perl` version..

Comment: The string `TIME` is not present in your original string

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks @Sundeep

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -E "s/^(([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}).*( [^:]*):.*( FIELD3\[[^]]*\]).*/\1\3\4/"
```